# Firebase realtime database snapshot not running?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to figure out how to fetch data from firebase and store it in a variable. The code i used works sometimes, but other times it just doesn't run. When I close and reopen it, it often doesn't run the code until i comment out different parts and run it. The parts I need to comment out seems to change every time, so I don't know what the issue is.

```
// Function that runs when the sign up submit button is pressed
function signup() {
  console.log("signup ran");
  firebase.database().ref().once("value", gotData);
}

// Snapshot function
function gotData(data) {
  console.log("gotData ran");

  dv = data.val()

  var tempcodes = dv.verifCodes;

  var codes = JSON.stringify(tempcodes);

  var codelist = codes.split(",")
  console.log(codelist);

  var vcode = document.getElementById("verifcode").value;

  if (codelist.indexOf(vcode) > -1){
    console.log("valid code");
  }
}
```

There are no error messages, and "gotData ran" is never printed to the console, while "signup ran" does.

I'm really new to firebase and still don't really understand how snapshots work in the first place, and the tutorials don't really explain it that well. Any help/advice is welcome!

Once again, though, I'd like to mention that this code works flawlessly when it's actually executing, and the only problem is that it isn't doing that. Thanks!

EDIT: So, something strange seems to be happening. I have a separate line of code adding data to the firebase that wasn't relevant, but that code still runs even when console.log doesn't. It looks like the code will affect the database, but won't run anything in the program? I really don't know what the issue is and I'm still kind of lost.

Comment: You're showing two functions, but you're not showing how they get invoked.  That seems to be where the problem exists, but we can't see that code.  Please edit the question to show all the relevant code in such a way that someone could reproduce the problem on their own.

Comment: The gotData function is invoked at
`firebase.database().ref().once("value", gotData);`

and the signup function is called by an html form onsubmit event.

EDIT: Hit submit early...

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what might be going on from the description. Can you reproduce the problem in a site like jsbin? That would allow us to see precisely what you are seeing, and makes it much more likely we can help.